# Shear in Object Mode not working

Tags: transforms, object-mode

As far as I understood, I can use transformations in Object Mode as a non-destructive way of applying translation, rotation, etc.

I want to do exactly that with a shear transformation, so that I can edit my mesh later on before it was deformed.

However, whenever I try to shear (Object -> Transform -> Shear) my standard 3D cube, I cannot see that the shearing has any effect on the object regardless of the value or axis entered. Translation, rotation, and scaling works fine, however, bending also does not work.

I do not have this problem in Edit Mode, but I prefer to have my object remain straight if I want to go back and make changes to the object.

Is it possible to shear an object in Object Mode?

Comment: I think shear in object mode is to shear along several objects.

Comment: So is there any other way of shearing non-destructive?

Comment: The reason why it works this way is that Blender holds the scaling transformation as 3 values (scale along X, Y, Z axes), not a transform matrix. This allows easier keyframing, but is inconvenient in cases like yours. For rotation, there are similar problems, and interestingly, you can pick a different rotation mode (e.g. quaternion) for each object - here, with scale, we don't have this option. Probably for some good reason :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shear in object mode is not intended to shear an object mesh but to shear several objects from their locations.

But you can use a *'lattice modifier'* in order to shear an object in non destructive way:

Above on left an object sheared in edit mode.

On right, another one with a lattice modifier. The object is not sheared but the lattice is itself sheared in edit mode.

[image]

To do it:

- Place a lattice at the object location.
- Add a lattice modifier to your object and set the lattice as 'object' in the modifier.
- Enter edit mode for the lattice.
- Shear the lattice.